# preg_match find only this special character "|" in string

Tags: php

Hi i want to find if string content this "|" this character.

example:-

```
$string = '$18,000 | new price'; 

if (preg_match('/[^|]/', $string)) {

}
else {

}
```

Comment: http://php.net/strpos

Comment: awesome thanks i think this will solve issue.

Comment: You are welcome. I also have posted the code with `strpos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work.

```
$string = '$18,000 | new price'; 

if (strpos($string , '|') === false) {
     // Not found.
}
else {
    // Found.
}
```

http://php.net/strpos

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is wrong. No need of `^` in this case. Should be -

```
preg_match('/[|]/', $string);
```

You can use `storpos` -

```
$string = '$18,000 | new price';
if(strpos($string, '|')) { ... }
```